# What is the best approch to save images and xml file in device (sqliteDB)

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am creating an iPhone application in which i have to store images and xml files locally in device (sqliteDB). So my question is what is the best way to do this?

I have two approaches in my mind.

1) Store images and xml in device and just save references of them in to sqliteDB.

2) Encode images and xml file to Base64 and save to sqliteDB directly.

Which will be more wise and why?

Do anyone have any other way to perform this by which application can run smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store both xml and images in (sqllite) i think it is best because we can perform CRUD operations .
[Saving and retrieving images to and from SQLite in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894337/saving-and-retrieving-images-to-and-from-sqlite-in-ios)
you can find how to save images in sqllite

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk_store-data/

above tutorial is about how to use sqllite in ios and save data in sqllite ,saving all these 
data in sqllite is a wise way to manage the resources ..

Comment: Hi. Yes you were right about CRUD operations. And thank you for guiding me in right direction. But for other users i want to mention that i have save files in sqlite with base64 encoding as binary file operations are bit tricky in sqlite and might get corrupt if something goes wrong during operation. So BASE64 encoding will nice option.